# Display name of user instead of user number

Tags: support, display-names

I am new to Stack Exchange. I have just created an account on Stack Overflow. I want to change the name in my profile so it is not just a user number.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sure, go to your profile and click "edit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to profile and above your [empty] bio it should say edit. Click. And then edit your "Display Name".

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. You can edit your current displayed username by edit the "Displayed Name" field on your edit account profile page. You can change your displayed username whenever you want. And it will be a history for the change of your displayed username on your profile.